# Does declaring a variable but not initializing it increase performance?

Tags: java, c++, c, initialization, declaration

I am currently learning computer science and want to understand everything, so I've noticed in books that people declare a variable `int x;` and then initialize it right below the declaration e.g.

```
int x;
x = 0;
```

I was wondering if that does anything positive to memory or efficiency of the compiled code?

Comment: You've left out a few language tags. While it's well known that C, C++, and Java all compile and run in a similar fashion, there are many other languages that behave similarly too.

Comment: namely? , these are the three that i know.

Comment: Got some many answers, but not many votes, lol, i love it. thanks for all the answers though.helped alot

Comment: @worlboss: In the future, please focus on one language at a time in your questions.

Comment: Sorry, will do. more tags = more viewers, you know?

Comment: @worlboss: more tags = more distraction if the question is not language specific. You're asking a question as if all the above languages compile the same and work the same, and nothing could be further from the truth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I currently learning computer science and want to understand everything

You have come to the right place!

> if that does something positive to memory or efficiency of the compiled code

It doesn't.  But how can you know that?  Empirical data, brother!

Take the time to study these two intermediate outputs from my compiler.   Here's a legend: the leftmost column is not interesting, ignore it.  The next column shows either the name of the source filename (`example2.c`) or the executable machine instructions (`0000 55`) which were generated from the source.   The lines from the original source are shown where you see four asterisks.  It's interleaved with the corresponding assembly output that was generated when compiling.  The instruction mnemomics and arguments are shown to the right of the executable instructions.  Look back and forth between the two examples, you can see that the instructions are the same in both examples.

I created these examples using `gcc` (`gcc -c -g -Wa,-ahl=example.s  example.c`).

First, with "sane" initialization:

```
   6                with_init:                                         
   7                .LFB0:
   8                    .file 1 "example2.c"                           
   1:example2.c    **** 
   2:example2.c    **** int with_init()                                
   3:example2.c    **** {
   9                    .loc 1 3 0
  10                    .cfi_startproc                                 
  11 0000 55            pushq   %rbp                                   
  12                .LCFI0:
  13                    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16                         
  14                    .cfi_offset 6, -16                             
  15 0001 4889E5        movq    %rsp, %rbp                             
  16                .LCFI1:
  17                    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6                        
   4:example2.c    ****     int x = 0;                                 
  18                    .loc 1 4 0
  19 0004 C745FC00      movl    $0, -4(%rbp)                           
  19      000000   
   5:example2.c    ****     
   6:example2.c    ****     return x;                                  
  20                    .loc 1 6 0
  21 000b 8B45FC        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax                         
   7:example2.c    **** }
  22                    .loc 1 7 0
  23 000e 5D            popq    %rbp                                   
  24                .LCFI2:
  25                    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8                              
  26 000f C3            ret
```

And now with the more "interesting" case you pose:

```
   6                later_init:
   7                .LFB0:
   8                    .file 1 "example.c"
   1:example.c     ****
   2:example.c     **** int later_init()
   3:example.c     **** {
   9                    .loc 1 3 0
  10                    .cfi_startproc
  11 0000 55            pushq   %rbp
  12                .LCFI0:
  13                    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
  14                    .cfi_offset 6, -16
  15 0001 4889E5        movq    %rsp, %rbp
  16                .LCFI1:
  17                    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
   4:example.c     ****     int x;
   5:example.c     ****
   6:example.c     ****     x = 0;
  18                    .loc 1 6 0
  19 0004 C745FC00      movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
  19      000000
   7:example.c     ****
   8:example.c     ****     return x;
  20                    .loc 1 8 0
  21 000b 8B45FC        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
   9:example.c     **** }
  22                    .loc 1 9 0
  23 000e 5D            popq    %rbp
  24                .LCFI2:
  25                    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
  26 000f C3            ret
```

No difference!

EDIT: I didn't see the `java` tag before.  Arguably even more straightforward in that case:

```
$ cat example.java 

class SOComparison
{

    public static int with_init()
    {
        int x = 0;

        return x;
    }

    public static int later_init()
    {
        int x;

        x = 0;

        return x;
    }

}
$ javap -c SOComparison
Compiled from "example.java"
class SOComparison {
  SOComparison();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public static int with_init();
    Code:
       0: iconst_0      
       1: istore_0      
       2: iload_0       
       3: ireturn       

  public static int later_init();
    Code:
       0: iconst_0      
       1: istore_0      
       2: iload_0       
       3: ireturn       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a very unusual compiler, this should not change anything in the compiled code.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the code readability, nothing changes: your compiler should figure out that the first assignment happens at some other place, and perform the assignment there.

In general, you should prefer combining initialization and assignment, except rare situations when the first assignment should happen in an inner scope to the one where the variable is declared, such as variables assigned inside `do`/`while` loops, and used after the loop's completion:

```
bool found; // No assignment
do {
    found = false;
    ...
    if (...) {
        found = true;
    }
    ...
} while (!finished(someCondition));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Java story:

for the simple class:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        int x = 0;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        int x;
        x = 0;
    }
}
```

we get the same bytecode in both cases:
[image]

Hence, since there is no difference between the two.  For reference, this was generated via:

```
javap -c MyClass.class
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally there will be no performance (and even code) difference if your variable is assigned in the same scope as it is declared. Any modern compiler should be able to do this kind of simple optimization nowadays. (If not throw it away and get a decent one.)

Where it can make a minimal difference if you pass the address of your variable to a function and initialize it there, before you did any assignment in the scope of the definition. But you'd really need good and performing code to note that, so you should first be concerned with readability and safety (never use unitialized memory) and only come back to such a point if you *measured* a sensible performance problem concerning *that* initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all on the assembly language scale. Check here http://gcc.godbolt.org/